# What is the minimum number of slots to cover a set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose there is a $n$-element set $S$, i.e., $\left|S\right|=n$.  One has a complete collection of $k$-element ($k<n$) subsets of $S$: $C=\left\{C_1,C_2,\ldots\right\}$, i.e., any subset of $S$ with $k$ elements are within collection $C$: $\forall T\subset S$, $|T|=k$, $T\in C$.  The question is: what is the minimum number $p$ of a subset of $C$, such that $\cup^p_{m=1}C_{k_m}$ covers $S$?  Is there a closed form for the solution, or one can only numerically calculate this number $p$?

Answer (score 1):

If $D\subset C$, and if $D$ has $q$ members, then the number of members of $\cup D$ is at most $q k$. So  for $S=\cup D$ we need $q k\geq n,$ hence $q\geq n/k.$ Now $q\geq n/k \iff q\geq 1+[(n-1)/k]$ where $[x]$ denotes the largest integer not exceeding $x$.

$$ \text {Let } \; p=1+[(n-1)/k].$$ Note that if $k$ is a divisor of $n$ then $p=n/k$.And if $k$ does not divide $n$ then $p=1+[n/k]$.

Let  $S=\{x(j):1\leq j\leq n\}.$  For $1\leq i\leq p-1$ let $C_i=\{x((i-1)k+j): 1\leq j\leq k\}.$ For brevity, let $T= \cup_{j=1}^{p-1} C_j.$ We have $T= \{x(i):1\leq i\leq k (p-1)\}.$

The number of members of $S$ \ $T$ is at most $k.$ So take $C_p\in C$   with $C_p\supset S$ \ $T$. $$ \text {So } \cup_{j=1}^pC_j=S.$$

We have shown that at least $p$ members of $C$  is necessary, and then shown that $p$ members of $C$ is sufficient.